# css - how to setup image editing page

Tags: css, image, layout, editing, fluid

I am trying to turn a mock-up into a page with css but I'm not sure if there are some tricks I am missing due to inexperience. The image below is what I want. I want the char menu to take up a fixed width but I want the editing menu to stretch as the browser window is re-sized.

[image: image editing page]

I don't seem to be able to use percentages for sizing the fluid part since it will either overflow under the chat box or make white space between it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is insufficient for anyone to help. You'll need to post more details as well as either a link to an example or actual code.

Comment: There is no code. All I have to go on is a picture. I'm simply asking if there is a positioning trick to use to solve the problem I described.

Comment: You should at least *try* to solve the problem yourself before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
html,body{width:100%; height:100%;}
.image{background:lightblue; height:100%; margin-right:200px;}
.menu{width:200px; height:100%; background:salmon; position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1951554)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But that does not work because the right sidebar goes over the left content. The more I think about it the more it sounds impossible. Is the solution perhaps javascript related?

By the way I did try to solve the problem but posted the code would be confusing as it is bloated with extraneous stuff in its current state.